# Not able to authenticate my Node js(v10.15.3) app, npm mysql (v2.17.1) with MySQL(8.0.15) (ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR)

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am running a simple Nodejs(v10.15.3) app trying to access MySQL server (8.0.15). npm mysql package version is v2.17.1.
The script is as shown below,

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'test',
    password: '2222',
    database: 'database',
    debug: true          
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        throw err;            
    }

    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

**Strange thing is I am able to login with same credentials from MySQL client.**
I have tried almost all approaches mentioned in other forums. Some of things which I have tried,

1. I have changed the password plugin type from `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password` for the user test.
2. Updated the password for the user and did flush privileges.

Attaching the entire stack trace.

```
<-- HandshakeInitializationPacket {
  protocolVersion: 10,
  serverVersion: '8.0.13',
  threadId: 71,
  scrambleBuff1: <Buffer 16 5c 10 12 68 49 73 68>,
  filler1: <Buffer 00>,
  serverCapabilities1: 65535,
  serverLanguage: 33,
  serverStatus: 2,
  serverCapabilities2: 50175,
  scrambleLength: 21,
  filler2: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
  scrambleBuff2: <Buffer 41 06 27 5a 0c 4c 4c 30 2f 72 0d 7e>,
  filler3: <Buffer 00>,
  pluginData: 'mysql_native_password',
  protocol41: true }

--> (71) ClientAuthenticationPacket {
  clientFlags: 455631,
  maxPacketSize: 0,
  charsetNumber: 33,
  filler: undefined,
  user: 'test',
  scrambleBuff:
   <Buffer fa ee eb f2 89 a4 f0 91 a9 d1 aa f2 77 08 76 bb ec a2 51 8b>,
  database: 'simplify_meetup',
  protocol41: true }

<-- (71) ErrorPacket {
  fieldCount: 255,
  errno: 1045,
  sqlStateMarker: '#',
  sqlState: '28000',
  message:
   'Access denied for user \'test\'@\'localhost\' (using password: YES)' }

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
    at D:\Development\simplify-meetup\routes\EventReminderAPI.js:20:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Development\simplify-meetup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

[image: Grants for the user 'test']

[image: MySQL server options file]

Comment: Have you checked if that `test` user account was indeed created using the `mysql_native_password` plugin? 

`select user, plugin from mysql.user where user = 'test';` If that's indeed the case, maybe the password is incorrect.

Comment: I have created the user with `mysql_native_password` plugin only. I am able to login with the same credentials in the mysql command line.

Comment: The mysql command line supports the `caching_sha2_password` plugin as well, so it does not help much in this case. There's no reason to get this error unless the password is incorrect (or the user does not even exist), which might mean the original value is indeed wrong, or the client (in this case the node.js one) is using an hashing algorithm that does not match the one used by the server-side authentication plugin selected when creating that user (which would definitely happen for the `caching_sha2_password` case, since there is no support yet).

Comment: @ruiquelhas, Is there a way to know the hashing algorithm which mysql package for nodejs is using internally? Is there a way I can pass the type of hashing to use ?

Comment: As far as I recall, that specific node.js driver supports [`mysql_old_password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/old-native-pluggable-authentication.html) and [`mysql_native_password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html). In any case, nether of them will work if you are using MySQL 8.0 and don't explicitly create user accounts with them (`mysql_old_password` is not even supported by the server anymore) because, by default, users are created using the `caching_sha2_password` plugin. What's the output of the query I mentioned before?

Comment: @ruiquelhas, I have updated the screenshot showing the list of users in mysql server along with the plugins they are using. I am using MySQL 8.0.15, you mean because of this both `mysql_old_password` and `mysql_native_password` will not work with node client ?

Comment: @ruiquelhas, Just now, I have seen the authentication method config for my MySQL 8.0.15 installation, I see it was set to use only `caching_sha2_password`, when I am try to change to legacy authentication method, strange that I am not able to login with my root password there. But, in command line with same credentials I am able to login.

Comment: @ruiquelhas, got the issue. Posted the answer below. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @ruiquelhas, What I observed is, after that if I restarted my system, again the auth is failing. I think once the restart of MySQL server is happening it is probably switching to the recommended approach to use latest authentication. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but you can use the `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` option when starting the server. More details available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password).

Comment: @ruiquelhas, Ok let me reiterate. I have reinstalled MySQL server with the legacy authentication method as mentioned in screenshot here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57728787/539472) and node is able to connect to MySQL server. After this, I restarted my system, post that when trying to connect node to MySQL was failing with ER_ACCESS_DENIED error. So, I was thinking probably, on restart when MySQL is starting with latest authentication method.

Comment: @ruiquelhas, I have added my.ini, server options file and there `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` is already present. But, still I am getting `ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR` when trying to connect node app with MySQL.

Comment: In theory it shouldn't really matter which default authentication plugin the server is using as long as the user account was created with a supported authentication plugin in the first time (in this case, `mysql_native_password` to work with the `mysql` Node.js module). I honestly can't understand what might be the problem here. You need to check which authentication plugin was used when creating the user account to be sure.

Comment: @ruiquelhas, I got the issue. If there are multiple instances of `mysqld.exe` present, in that case it was giving authentication error. For instance post restart of the system, multiple `mysqld.exe` instances are present and it was giving error.

Comment: @ruiquelhas, Do you think it does not matter which authentication method we use during the installation? Then why do we need two options?

Comment: I meant the `default_authentication_plugin` option shouldn't matter as soon as the user account is created. It only matters if you don't explicitly provide the plugin to use when doing that. It does not matter if the server restarts or not, that specific user account was created with a specific authentication plugin which does not change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. If you have installed MySQL version 8.0.4 and higher, you will be given the option to select the latest authentication method or to support legacy authentication methods as well. If the first option is selected, MySQL server supports only `caching_sha2_password`. The other legacy option supports `mysql_native_password`.

Since, currently npm mysql client package does not support latest authentication method and me selecting latest authentication method at MySQL server, I was facing this issue.

The option screen will look as below. Post changing the option, it worked like charm.

[image]

Thanks @ruiquelhas for guiding me about the potential issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the test user has permission to access the db;
In a mysql shell run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'localhost';
```

This will let you see all the databases that user has access to.

Comment: I have added the screenshot listing the grants for the user. It has access to all the databases.